# "Sending request" popping up on iPhone repetitively

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6S currently running 12.4.1.
The following pop-up keeps showing up every now and then. Upto 50 times a day.

It's very annoying and prohibits any activity while it shows.
I have searched a lot what this is, in vain.

Any way to get rid of this?

[image: ][sending request popup, dismiss button]

Answer (score -2):

a scam.
hold the two buttons (on/off and finger at the bottom), keep holding, keep holding, after you see the white apple logo, keep holding another 2 seconds, then let go and let it startup.

Comment: Anywhere on the Internet I can read about this?